# split a column to two column with duplicates on the ID using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, duplicates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0md2.png)

Hello, does someone have an idea to help to split a column in two columns. I have duplicates in my Id columns so i have some difficulties if someone can lay me some track, i would appreciate a lot.

there is a png to illustrate my situation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby function and then aggregate the values.

```
df = df.groupby('Id').agg({'Date': ['min', 'max']}).reset_index()
```